# How can I mount ephemeral storage on a windows ec2 instance using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I have an AMI with Windows Server 2008 as an EBS root device.  I can start it an instance using boto and remote desktop into it, but I cannot seem to get it mount its ephemeral storage.  Is something wrong with my BlockDeviceMapping?

Here is my code:

```
import boto
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
conn = EC2Connection(mykey, mysecretkey)
bdm = boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping.BlockDeviceMapping({'/dev/xvdb':'ephemeral0'})
conn.run_instances(myami, key_name=mykeyname,security_groups=[mysecgroup],block_device_map=bdm)
```

When I run this code, an instance fires up and I can access, but I only see the root device mounted.

Comment: I don't know boto, but this just looks like it is mapping a device name to a device driver -- but doesn't do anything to format or mount the device into the namespace.

Comment: @sarnold hmmmmm.  my reading of the documentation seems to indicate that aws will do the mounting for you, but i could be wrong.  see the 'Accessing Instance Stores on Amazon EBS-backed Windows Instances' section here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had seen some examples which led me to believe that the block device map should be a string to string map, but it should actually be a string to BlockDeviceType map.  Here is how I got it to work:

```
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
from boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping import BlockDeviceType, BlockDeviceMapping
conn = EC2Connection(mykey, mysecretkey)
xvdb = BlockDeviceType()
xvdb.ephemeral_name='ephemeral0'
bdm = BlockDeviceMapping()
bdm['/dev/xvdb'] = xvdb
conn.run_instances(myami, key_name=mykeyname,security_groups=[mysecgroup],block_device_map=bdm)
```

When I logged in, I could see my ephemeral drive.  Not that it does not show up in the AWS management console as a block device.  You still only see your root device.

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/boto-users/browse_thread/thread/ee281f1ccf420a19/26a72f3c9341526b) is a code sample / forum question that helped me figure it out.